# if-then statements involving signals

Tags: if-statement, frp, elm

I am getting stuck writing a simple if-then statement in Elm involving signals.

What if the conditional is itself a `Signal` type?  I would like to change the [Mouse Down](http://elm-lang.org/examples/mouse-is-down) example on the Elm website:

```hs
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Mouse

main : Signal Element
main =
  Signal.map show Mouse.isDown
```

It will either say **True** or **False** depending on whether the Mouse is up or down.  What if I want it to say "Up" or "Down"?  My Boolean function could say:

```
<!-- language: haskell -->

f : Bool -> String
f x = 
 if x then "&uarr;" else "&darr;"
```

but when I change the main function I get a type mismatch.

```
<!-- language: haskell -->

main : Signal Element
main =
  Signal.map show ( f Mouse.isDown)
```

Error #1:

```
The 2nd argument to function `map` has an unexpected type.

10|   Signal.map show ( f Mouse.isDown)
As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    Signal a

    String
```

Error #2:

```
The 1st argument to function `f` has an unexpected type.

10|   Signal.map show ( f Mouse.isDown)
As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    Bool

    Signal Bool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same thing as with `show :: Bool -> Element`. You're not passing the Signal into that function, but rather you `map` the function over the Signal. It works the same with your `f`:

```hs
import Mouse
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)

f : Bool -> String
f x = if x then "&uarr;" else "&darr;"

updown : Signal String
updown = Signal.map f Mouse.isDown

main : Signal Element
main = Signal.map show updown
```

Or in short, with composition: `main = Signal.map (show << f) Mouse.isDown`.